# If $Rx$ is nil then $Rxr$ is nil for any $r \in R$

Tags: noncommutative-algebra

i am studying kothe's conjecture, ad got stuck here. if $R$  is any non commutative ring, then how is it true that if the ideal $Rx$ is nil then $Rxr$ is nil for any $r \in R$.

let $sx\in Rx$, then $(sx)^n=0$ for some $n$, but how is $sxr$  nilpotent for any $r\in R$.

Comment: What is $x$ here? Just some indeterminate?

Comment: x is any element of R.

Comment: Note, you don't want that $sx$ nilpotent implies $sxr$ is nipotent, but that every element of $Rx$ is nilpotent implies $sxr$ is nilpotent for any $s,r\in R$.

Answer (score 5):

Notice that $$(sxr)^n = (sxr)(sxr)\cdots(sxr) = sx(rsx)\cdots(rsx)r = sx(rsx)^{n-1}r.$$ Because $rsx \in Rx$ and this left ideal is nil, for sufficiently large $n$ the expression above is zero.

Comment: also can you clear my this doubt that let x be any element of a nil left ideal say I. then (x)=RxR is nil. is it true?

Comment: A positive answer to your question is equivalent to Koethe's conjecture: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_a_ring#The_upper_nil_radical_or_K.C3.B6the_radical